# GAE and JPA - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.store.ExecutionContext.findObject

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I'm using Google app engine and JPA for my application.
I need to call REST API to insert and get records.Insertion of the records to the table works fine,but when I use select query it is giving tons of error.

Error Trace is :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.store.ExecutionContext.findObject(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/datanucleus/store/FieldValues;Ljava/lang/Class;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery.entityToPojoPrimaryKey(DatastoreQuery.java:543)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery.access$100(DatastoreQuery.java:115)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$1.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:221)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$1.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:219)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveNext(LazyResult.java:96)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveAll(LazyResult.java:121)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.size(LazyResult.java:115)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult.size(StreamingQueryResult.java:151)
at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.toArray(AbstractQueryResult.java:400)
at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(Unknown Source)
at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.JavaQueryEvaluator.execute(JavaQueryEvaluator.java:160)
at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.JPQLEvaluator.execute(JPQLEvaluator.java:112)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPQLQuery.performExecute(JPQLQuery.java:200)
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1789)
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1693)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:185)
```

And for select query I use CriteriaAPI of JPA :

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Technology> cq = cb.createQuery(Technology.class);
Root<Technology> e = cq.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Technology.class));
cq.where(cb.equal(e.get(Technology_.name), {technologyName}));
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
List<Technology> list = query.getResultList();
```

And my Technology class is :
    @Entity
    public class Technology implements Serializable{

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "TechnologyID")
private Long technologyID;

@Column(name = "Name")
private String name;

public Long getTechnologyID() {
    return technologyID;
}

public void setTechnologyID(Long technologyID) {
    this.technologyID = technologyID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

And there is a entity SignalStrength which has many to one relation with Technology:

```
@Entity
public class SignalStrength {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "SignalStrengthID")
private Long signalStrengthID;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TechnologyID")
private Technology technology;

@Column(name = "SignalStrengthValue")
private int signalStrengthValue;
public Long getSignalStrengthID() {
    return signalStrengthID;
}

public void setSignalStrengthID(Long signalStrengthID) {
    this.signalStrengthID = signalStrengthID;
}
public Technology getTechnology() {
    return technology;
}

public void setTechnology(Technology technology) {
    this.technology = technology;
}

public int getSignalStrengthValue() {
    return signalStrengthValue;
}

public void setSignalStrengthValue(int signalStrengthValue) {
    this.signalStrengthValue = signalStrengthValue;
}
}
```

And datanucleus dependencies :

```
<!-- Datanucleus dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchMethodError means that you screwed up the jars you have in the CLASSPATH. One of the jars is not consistent with another one. In this case the jars with datanucleus in the name are the ones you've got inconsistent.

Since you say nothing about which one's you're using then you'll have to work out which based on Google docs (or actually mention them ...). This page tells you all you need to know about consistent versions https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility

Comment: Neil,Thank you.But I don't think I have conflicting jars in my classpath and I have updated my datanucleus dependencies.

Comment: If you had consistent versions you wouldn't get NoSuchMethodError, fact. And "datanucleus.version" is? I added a link to my answer which defines the consistent versions needed

Comment: Thank you Neil.I'm trying to figure out which version of DN I should use for appengine 1.9.15.Currently my DN version is 3.1.3.

Comment: that page i linked tells you what version of DN jars to use with the datanucleus-appengine jar. So decide which version of that jar you're using